# 401 error when requesting OAuth access credentials using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth

So I'm putting together a quick and dirty app to add new posts automatically to Tumblr based on new items pulled from an RSS feed. The app is in Codeigniter, and so far I've managed to obtain the request credentials and sent the user to Tumblr for authorisation. The problem is, once they're redirected back to the app and I make a request for the access credentials, I'm getting the following error:

```
Message: file_get_contents(http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_consumer_key=THECONSUMERKEY&oauth_nonce=9362afdd34f9ce1601fb9cf505ffa3cf&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1327440390&oauth_token=09mFsxCvsODDmSxPCyQNu4QKFMMXaAEEyPtBibPUyUTE1n2BsJ&oauth_verifier=hDfGgesf9EKIO5yFhiHxtnsbP42XEP1FISY2qyyWerzXf6fPTG&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=yeFw8ACvVvKtD%2BQ%2FdzbLivDSm1Y%3D) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$oauthVerifier = $_GET["oauth_verifier"];
        $sigBase = "GET&" . rawurlencode($this->accessTokenUrl) . "&"
                . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey)
                        . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($this->nonce)
                        . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($this->oauthSignatureMethod)
                        . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $this->oauthTimestamp
                        . "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode($this->CI->session->userdata('requestToken'))
                        . "&oauth_verifier=" . rawurlencode($oauthVerifier)
                        . "&oauth_version=" . $this->oauthVersion);
        $sigKey = $this->consumerSecret . "&";
        $oauthSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $sigBase, $sigKey, true));

        $requestUrl = $this->accessTokenUrl . "?"
                . "oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey)
                . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($this->nonce)
                . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($this->oauthSignatureMethod)
                . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($this->oauthTimestamp)
                . "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode($this->CI->session->userdata('requestToken'))
                . "&oauth_verifier=" . rawurlencode($oauthVerifier)
                . "&oauth_version=" . rawurlencode($this->oauthVersion)
                . "&oauth_signature=" . rawurlencode($oauthSig);

        $response = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
```

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The stray ampersand was actually not in the original code (my bad), but something I did afterwards when trying to fix it. In fact, the cause of the original problem was the absence of the Request Token Secret in the signature key.

Thanks for the pointers, aitchnyu - in the end, the problem was a stray ampersand. In the signature base, I wrapped the ampersand before "oauth_consumer_key=" in a rawurlencode, when it should have come before it.

Here's the old sig base:

```
"GET&" . rawurlencode($this->accessTokenUrl)
                . rawurlencode("&oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey)
                        . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($this->nonce)
                        . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($this->oauthSignatureMethod)
                        . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($this->time)
                        . "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode($token)
                        . "&oauth_verifier=" . rawurlencode($oauthVerifier)
                        . "&oauth_version=" . $this->oauthVersion);
```

The new one:

```
"GET&" . rawurlencode($this->accessTokenUrl) . "&"
                . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($this->consumerKey)
                        . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($this->nonce)
                        . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($this->oauthSignatureMethod)
                        . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($this->time)
                        . "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode($token)
                        . "&oauth_verifier=" . rawurlencode($oauthVerifier)
                        . "&oauth_version=" . $this->oauthVersion);
```

Vital difference!

Comment: And I believe you never made that mistake in the code for getting request tokens. When I said, "consumer key successfully got you a request token", I didnt assume that you inadvertently mangled it.

Answer (score 1):

This is incomplete and needs some bug chasing by you.

Do understand the relevant part of the conversation:

```
TumApp to user: please go to Tumblr with one of my request tokens: GHF3F4F

user to Tumblr: I authorize TumApp, and here is it's request token: GHF3F4F

Tumblr to itself: let me authorize GHF3F4F, which TumApp can exchange for an access token
       to user: redirect to Tumapp's callback

Tumapp to itself: Great, user authorized me (by requesting my callback). Let me exchange my request token for an access token
       to Tumblr: Hey, give me an access token for GHF3F4F

Tumblr to Tumapp: Epic 401 fail!
```

---

Here are the reasons why Tumblr would give a 401

From http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#http_codes

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    Invalid Consumer Key
    Invalid / expired Token
    Invalid signature
    Invalid / used nonce
```

I would deduce starting with the token; the consumer key successfully got you a request token and the signature and nonce are generated by the library.